# Perforce Force Get Latest Not Working?

Tags: perforce

I have a large software project that some folks have just started dumping things into (instead of creating a development branch!!! ARG!!) incrementally as they make sweeping changes. There are problems with some of the things they did, and of course they are on holiday. So I used Perforce to try to get the baseline at a particular point in time. Perforce claimed to get all the files at that point in time, but it did not build. I know that it did build originally, as our CruiseControl successfully built it at that point in the history.

So obviously something is wrong with Perforce.
Below is some fabulous ASCII art showing the structure of the checkins to Perforce. Letters indicate different developers, numbers indicate their checkins.

```
Newest
    D 18
    D 17   Changed the contents of the files in D 16
    D 16   They did some `move/delete` and `add/delete` here
    D 15
    D 14
    D 13
    D 12
    C 1
    B 2
    D 11
    D 10
    D 9
    D 8
    D 7
    D 6
    D 5
    D 4
    A 3
    A 2
    D 3
    D 2
    D 1
    B 1
    A 1
Oldest
```

D18 doesn't work. D17 does, but I want to test at B2 to simplify things.

C1 is the CruiseControl version that built and ran just fine when it built last week. It only changed the version number in a text file. No big deal.

I want B2, so I do a Force get at B2. It doesn't build, even though it did when I checked it in. So I remove all the files and do a Force get at B2. It still doesn't build. I wondered what I could have done to it, and finally decided to try to get even earlier.

If I go all the way down and get A1, it builds. I can then get B2 and it will build (even if I delete all the files from A1!!). I can keep going up until D16, which does not build. D17 does build. The interesting thing is when I go up the tree, from oldest to newest, B2 builds and runs fine. When I go down the tree from D16 or newer, B2 does not build nor run. If I start at A1, and go up the tree to D15 and then go back down the tree to B2, it builds and works. Once I have gotten D16, **nothing** older builds unless I go all the way back to A1. I don't understand the linkage/problem. There seems to be no connection between A1 and D16 at all. A1 is a simple data file change which isn't even compiled. A1 was before these guys started dumping sweeping changes into the baseline, but even then, I expect Perforce to be able to replicate a changelist the **exact** same moving either direction in time.

I have been operating under the impression that if I do a "force get" on a particular changelist, then I will get --**everything** that was checked in at that point in time (yes, I understand you can ask Perforce to only give you that changelist's files, but I did not do that).

- I have nothing checked out in this repository.
- I delete all the files each time.
- I do a `Force` get every time.

I can build now, but I want to be able to trust my configuration management tool. What am I missing? What other information can help to debug this?

Edit about my environment:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Perforce Server 2013.1/628821
- Perforce Visual Client/NTX64/2013.2/661179
- Using QNX Momentics 4.6 to cross-compile to QNX 6.4.1 for x86

---

Additional Update:
While this is probably not exactly related, I just ran into a situation where the GUI, P4V was confused and made it look like the backend was confused, when it was not.

There was a file that the GUI claimed I had edited and removed one line, when I had not. I did a force get latest, and it still looked like it. I deleted the file, then got the latest, and it still claimed I had edited it. I closed P4V and reopened it, to find the file was as I expected it to be. Somehow, the GUI got confused. So the takeaway is: if it looks weird, restart the GUI and see if that helps. **Maybe** this could have helped with my issue above.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem that you're seeing is because of the source files?  Depending on your environment (not disclosed), there might be temporary or build files which aren't getting purged, but get rebuilt when going as far back as A1, and thus aren't causing you problems when you come forward from there.   Just speculating at this point.

Comment: It definitely seems like you are struggling with force-syncing across the changelist which contains the MOVE operation. You don't mention what version of the server and/or client you are using. Also, it sounds like you are using P4V or some other visual client; for this sort of precise control you may find you get better results by using the command-line and learning to use tools like 'p4 sync -f -n @N' and 'p4 have'.

Comment: @gaige I thought that might be the case, but the problem persisted across a delete of the entire folder and a force get and rebuild, which means that everything was purged when I did this test. And the problem didn't occur in the other direction using the same method. Weird.

Comment: @BryanPendleton I'll give that a try. I updated the question with the versions of Perforce that I'm using.